# Bootstrap column goes over another column element that has position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a button in between bootstrap columns using position absolute.

My problem is that once my button enters another column, the button goes under the column instead going over it.

What I want to Achieve
[image]

What I have
[image]

My Html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <ol>
        <li>
          Option 
          <button class="btn btn-default feedback-option--feedback-button">PressMe</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          Option 
          <button class="btn btn-default feedback-option--feedback-button">PressMe</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          Option 
          <button class="btn btn-default feedback-option--feedback-button">PressMe</button>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs   col-sm-9">
      Main Body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my CSS

```
.feedback-body--main-content {
  background-color: #003B59;
}
.feedback-sidebar--main-content {
  background-color: red;
}
.global--row-no-padding [class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.feedback-option--feedback-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -30px;
}
.feedback-option-content {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: does adding `z-index: 2;` to your button's css solve this? I'm a little unsure of what you're having issues with.

Comment: @Widget It did solve my problem... Sorry I didn't knew this thing existed. Thanks. But out of curiosity are there any other ways to make sure my button would be up top ? z-index feels like a hack.

Comment: Putting the buttons after the main body is the other way. I'll write out a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla has [a good write-up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) of the order in which things are put on top of each other. Here's a summary:

- Elements that appear first in the markup go under those that appear later.
- Within each context (generally just the whole page), you can specify what order things stack with a `z-index`. Higher numbers are on top of smaller numbers.

Usually when absolutely positioning things you'll need to give it a z-index for it to show up right, assuming you'd like to keep your code in a semantically sensible order.